# Is eviews the only object oriented GUI based statistical package on the market?

Tags: software

I am trying to find a good and neat GUI statistical package for beginner, so far I have tried Stata, Gretl and Eviews.

Only Eviews seem to have objects (models, graphics etc) stored together with the data file, which is a big plus because everything is on one file.

I tried Gretl, it stores objects onto a "session" file. It's okay but the GUI looks bad and I heard that it is not has powerful as it's proprietary counterparts.

Stata is even worse, it saves every object as a separate file, graph is gph, results is in log file etc.

So is eviews the only GUI objects oriented statistical package on the market?

Not interested in learning R at the moment, I want to get my the concepts down with a GUI based software.

Thanks.

Comment: In Stata, the `estimates` command can do some of this. For example, you can save estimation results along with the data, so that when you open the data, they are available. There's also a tool called Project Manager that you may find interesting.

Comment: If lack of a GUI is the only reason for you not to use R, have a look at [Rcommander](http://www.rcommander.com/).

Comment: I don't know if this is a stupid reason, but the reason I'm not learning R is because the text I'm required to study for my econometrics course is called "Principles of Econometrics", And they have all the supplementary text called "Using Stata (or Eviews or Gretl) for Principles of Econometrics". But there is no R supplementary material for POE. 

So in order for me to study this textbook I must resort to use one of the statistical packaged that has a supplementary material for this textbook. 

But in the long run, I suppose R would be more beneficial.

Comment: I think I'd've found a statistical programming language rather useful when I was learning basic concepts - loops make it easy to investigate what happens under repeated sampling. [Mills (2002), *J. Stat. Educ.*, **10**, 1](http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v10n1/mills.html).

Comment: Just installed and played around with Rcommander, it's not even in the same window, and it's not anywhere near as powerful as Stata's GUI.